# How to print the exact JSON that is received on the server side in a REST call?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

I am using fasterxml to convert JSON to java.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am consistently getting `400 Bad Request` when I hit the service from UI. Whereas the call works fine from Advanced REST client.

How can I print the JSON that I am received on the backend(java side)?

I tried using the @ControllerAdvice annotation. It is giving me a stacktrace as below. But it does not print the exact input JSON.

> 13:30:12,563 WARN  [com.att.um.controller.ControllerConfig] (default
>   task-36) Returning HTTP 400 Bad Request:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
>   Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of
>   com.att.um.web.services.rest.model.JsonRequest out of START_ARRAY
>   token  at [Source:
>   io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl@43e804cf; line: 1,
>   column: 1]; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not
>   deserialize instance of com.att.um.web.services.rest.model.JsonRequest
>   out of START_ARRAY token  at [Source:
>   io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl@43e804cf; line: 1,
>   column: 1]    at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:228)
>   [spring-web-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:220)
>   [spring-web-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:138)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:178)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:98)
>   [spring-webmvc-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]

Comment: It would be helpful if you put in your Rest API code and the UI code with which you are trying to call the API service.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Jackson` already does that for you if you annotate your `Controller` implementation.
 Ex:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
public class YourControllerImpl implements YourController {

@Autowired
private YourService yourService;

@Override
public ResponseEntity addObject(@RequestBody Object obj) {
    yourService.addObject(obj);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
  }
}
```

Method `yourService.addObject(obj);` can have a backend logic ex: 
`Object myObj = new Object(obj)` or `Object myObj = new Object().from(obj)` or `Object myObj = new Object();` and use `getters & setters`

And the `API` might look like:

```
@RequestMapping("/object")
public interface YourController {

@PostMapping
ResponseEntity addObject(@RequestBody Object obj);
```

`@RequestBody` will get your `JSON` object sent via `POST`. You can `System.out.println(obj)` if you want to see what you are sending. You should also implement `DTOs`.